# Which email client should I use to determine if an email has been sent using C#

Tags: c#, email-client, outlook, wpf

I am creating a crypto-tool for my workplace and a feature of it, is that it opens **Outlook** as a popup so the user can send the **Encrypted file as an attachment** by mail and the Decryption Code automatically by SMS. But before i can send that SMS I have to determine if the email **has been sent** beforehand. 
Is there an email client I could use to easily know if the mail has been sent?

Which one would you recommend?